# Resolve hostnames with arch linux

Tags: archlinux, static-ip

I have a Pi that runs hostapd and dhcpd on arch linux to create it's own land with the Pi's (routers) IP being `10.0.0.1`. This uses the wlan0 interface and it only serves as a standalone router running a web server.

Once I connect to the Pi, I use `10.0.0.1` to display the web pages, but I want to use a hostname such as `firepi`. I have tried using dnsmasq, but I haven't been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated especially if you can give me some detailed examples as I am a novice.

The purpose of this system is that I have created a web app that you can use to ignite fireworks over WiFi at a safe distance. I would just like the convenience of using a hostname instead of the IP address.

Comment: did you check dnsmasq are running? if it's running, you should able use firepi.local as hostname.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a private network address it could be sufficient to edit the /etc/hosts file of any Linux computer wanting to use the name and not IP address.  Yours could looking something like this

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost
10.0.0.1     firepi
10.0.0.2     otherbox
```

You should allocate firepi and otherbox static ip addresses to avoid confusion when firepi is not running and another computer is allocated 10.0.0.1